# Need to execute several transactions as fast as possible

Tags: contract-invocation, security, gas-price, recovery

In the case of an emergency (e.g. theft), it may be necessary to disable several accounts as fast as possible.

I am writing the smart contract.

Should each of several accounts be disabled in a separate transaction or do one transaction with an array of accounts to be disabled?

- If we split into several independent transactions, each transaction uses less gas and thus passes through faster.
- If we do one transaction, it requires a fewer number of transactions. Will this work faster?
- If there are several transactions, need to manage (repeat if stalled with not enough gas price) each transactions separately.

Comment: The correct thing to do is to implement a function which takes as input a list of the accounts to be disabled (or start/end index, or start index + number of accounts, etc).

Comment: This allows you to control the size of the transaction (amount of gas required) and make sure that it is not too large (say, not larger than 0.5 of the average block gas limit), and will execute quickly enough.

Comment: It also allows you to effectively be confident that the transaction size does not exceed the block gas-limit altogether, meaning that the transaction will be un-executable (i.e., you should avoid having a function in your code which iterates a list of accounts without restricting the number of iterations to some maximum length).

Comment: @goodvibration But how is it better than to make N transactions for N accounts to be disabled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your concept of "speed" is a bit wrong. Transactions which utilize less gas are not faster.

Assuming that your transaction fits inside a block the only thing which affects the transaction speed is the *gas price*. The size of the transaction mostly does not affect the speed. Miners mostly order the transactions they take in their blocks by their gas price - so the higher gas price you give the faster you transaction gets process (included in a block).

So one transaction is always better for speed than multiple. With multiple transactions you face all sorts of managerial problems which you just don't need.

Comment: `Transactions which utilize less gas are not faster` - AFAIK, miners opt for higher gas price / lower gas first. This is because with lower gas price, they can essentially "squeeze more" into the same block. So given two transactions with the same gas price, the one with lower gas would be picked first. Again - AFAIK.

Comment: That's a valid theory. One might also claim the opposite: if they choose the bigger one they already get block fuller with high gas price stuff. But in reality would have to dig into client code (and real miner configurations) to know for sure.